# AJAX variable isn't passing through to the if statement

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When I alert the userID, I get the correct number alerted from the else statement.
The if statement won't alert at all. So I assume something is wrong with the condition i placed there.

The weird part is, even though the else statement, my div will not change color but it does alert correctly so I am confused.

**AJAX function**

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'status.php',
   dataType: "json",
   type: 'GET',
   success: function(data) {
       if (data.message === "online"){
           $('.status #user'+data.userId).css({background: '#40A547'});  
       } else{ 
            //alert(data.userId);
           $('.status #user'+data.userId).css({background: '#7f8c8d'});
       }
   }
});
```

**status.php**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$array = array();

if (logged_in() === true){
    $res8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_num_rows($res8) > 0){
        while($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8)){
            if ($row8['status'] === "1") {                  
                $array['message'] = 'online';
                $array['userId'] = $row8['user_id'];
            }
        }
    }
}


 else {  
   $array['message'] = 'offline'; 
   $array['userId'] = '2'; // just for testing
}

    echo json_encode($array);
```

**The div**

```
<div class="status" id="user2">test</div>
```

Comment: Where is and how are you using the `logged_in()` function? There's no other reference to it in your question/code.

Comment: it's just a function that does this: return (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) ? true : false;

Comment: Alert `data.message` before the condition. What output you get?

Comment: I get "offline" alerted

Comment: @Gadgetster Have you included the file where `logged_in()` function declare? Also do `var_dump(logged_in())` and tell us the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
$('.status #user'+data.userId)
----------^ <--- See space
```

You have no childNodes inside `.status`

Instead try this:

```
$('#user'+data.userId)
```

Also removed the `.status` selector as the ID will be specific.

Comment: Or better yet, remove `.status` from the selector as the ID part will be specific enough.

Comment: that worked! .status has a general layout that i gave it. also, the post has to have a color before doing the check for the first time right? also, how can i fix the if statement now for when i log in?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this block

```
if ($row8['status'] === "1") {                  
    $array['message'] = 'online';
    $array['userId'] = $row8['user_id'];
}
```

is never triggering.  $row8['status'] is always 0 coming back from the database.  Your fallback statement setting the message to offline doesn't trigger unless the database fails all together.

You should run this PHP test case:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$array = array();

$array['message'] = 'online'; 
$array['userId'] = '2'; // just for testing
```

And confirm the JQuery fixes from above.  Then go back to the database and verify the actual logged in case.

Comment: yeah that's what i figured to do as well. thanks for the input!